# Group mod center is perfect structure result

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, exact-sequence, simple-groups

Suppose that
$$
1 \to Z(G) \to G \to P \to 1
$$
is a short exact sequence of groups where $ P $ is perfect and $ Z(G) $ is the center of $ G $. Must it be the case that $ G $ is the direct product of a perfect group and an abelian group?

Comment: What happens if G = GL(V), with V a finite dimensional vector space over a field?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez $ GL(n,F)=F^\times \times SL(n,F) $ and $ F^\times $ is abelian and $ SL(n,F) $ is perfect right?

Comment: @Ian: it's not a direct product.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I guess what probably is true is that 
 contains a perfect central extension of $ P $
 and $ G $
 has the structure of a central product of that perfect central extension of $ P $
 with an abelian group?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira   Your claim is true if Z(G) and the Schur multiplier of P have coprime order.

Comment: @NourddineSnanou I see so if $ Z(G) $
 and the Schur multiplier of $ P $
 have coprime order then $ G $ will always split as a direct product of a perfect group and an abelian group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this has probably been answered in the comments, but the answer is no, and a counterexample is a central product of ${\rm SL}(2,5)$ with $C_4$, where $P={\rm PSL}(2,5) \cong A_5$, and $Z(G) \cong C_4$.

Comment: Is it at least always true that $ G $ will have a subgroup that is a perfect central extension of $ P $?

Comment: Your example is the index $ 2 $ subgroup $ SL^{\pm}(2,5) $ of $ GL(2,5) $. That is, the determinant $ \pm 1 \in \mathbb{F}_5 $ matrices. $ SL^{\pm}(2,5) $ is a central product of $ SL(2,5) $ with the group $ C_4 \cong <diag(2,2)> $ of scalar matrices. The central product is taken by modding out over the intersection of these two groups, which is the group of determinant 1 scalar matrices $ C_2 \cong <diag(4,4)> $. So we get a SES $ 1 \to C_4 \to SL^{\pm}(2,5) \to A_5 \to 1 $. $ G=SL^{\pm}(2,5) $ contains the perfect central extension $ SL(2,5) $ of $ P=A_5 $, but $ G $ is not a direct product.

Comment: Yes the derived group of $G$ has that property.

Comment: Could you say more about why, for an arbitrary group, $ G/Z(G) $ perfect implies $ [G,G] $ perfect? I know the reverse implication fails because $ [S_5,S_5]=A_5 $ is perfect but $ S_5/Z(S_5)=S_5 $ is not perfect.

Comment: I'll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll do it and add it as an update to my question!